# how to select and serialize data of different form with the same javascript funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to php and javascript /jquery.. and I'm italian, so forgive my english.

I want to use only one funcion in button (onclick) to use it in different form in the same page, and after I want to get the data of the form using serialize funcion. So i can't use the selector $(form#myform) because the different form have differen id.

This is the html

```
<form id="myform_1">        
    <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
        <option value="standard">standard</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="giorni" value="90"/>
    <input type="number" name="attesa" value="1"/>  
    <button type="button" onclick="FormManipulator()">Crea</button>
</form>
```

This is the function i'v tried

```
function FormManipulator(){
  var form_new = $(this).parents("form");
  var data = form_new.serialize();
  alert("data: " + data);
}
```

But i cant get the data of th input... the alert is empty. Where is my error? Can someone explain and give the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `$(this)` on a function refers to what .. but I think its not referring to the exact element you want so you need to pass `FormManipulator(ThisForm)` in  your function and use it like `FormManipulator(this)`

You can use something like this

```js
function FormManipulator(ThisForm){
  var form_new = $(ThisForm).closest("form");
  var data = form_new.serialize();
  alert("data: " + data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform_1">        
    <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
        <option value="standard">standard</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="giorni" value="90"/>
    <input type="number" name="attesa" value="1"/>  
    <button type="button" onclick="FormManipulator(this)">Crea</button>
</form>

<form id="myform_2">        
    <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
        <option value="standard">standard</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="giorni" value="90"/>
    <input type="number" name="attesa" value="1"/>  
    <button type="button" onclick="FormManipulator(this)">Crea</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @PalmiroLousse like I said on updated answer .. the problem with `$(this)`

Comment: You're totally welcome @PalmiroLousse .. Have a great day :-)